# Best way to disable a file in Windows File Explorer?

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I am working on a virtual file system on windows in C++,

I am currently looking for a Windows API to make a file visible but not accessible in Windows 7 and Higher,

Picture example

[image]

the best option I could found is to use FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE attribute, 
but this solution implies to have the windows [X] grey overlay on files,
[Offline Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx)

I already found this related post explaining the issue of file explorer multiple access if I hook the behavior at kernel side :
[Keep windows trying to read a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587521/keep-windows-trying-to-read-a-file),

is there an other way to look at the problem I omited, or a better option ?

Comment: What is the meaning of a file being disabled? How does it differ from being offline?

Comment: an offline file can be usable offline with windows offline files, in my case I want to block any interaction with the file.

Comment: You haven't explained how you are achieving any of this. How are you presenting these objects to the shell?

Comment: I have two option, use a callback in the file system adding the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE flag on the file, or using a shell extension to  block file access. I am currently exploring both options.

Comment: Neither of those sound like the right approach. Surely you want a namespace extension.

Comment: are you searching for a "legal" and documented way or an "internal" way?

Comment: This doesn't seem to add up.  If you disallow certain operations in Explorer, are you also wanting them prevented from a command/power-shell, cygwin, any other program with the ability to read or write files...?  If so, is there some program that's actually supposed to have access?

Comment: @MarcoA. Actualy I'd like to have a "legal" and documented way, but I did not found any right know.

Comment: @TonyD. Regarding from the user Interface, I want to avoid I/O errors shown to the user, from shell side those errors are acceptable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am exploring namespace extension, that what I meant by shell extension, I didn't know the name.